# Guarantee the lock is exclusive on the table for read also

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a web application and came across the problem to keep a value in column that is identical in two rows only and both goes in single batch of execution. One way I came up with solution to read the MAX value in the column and increment by 1. Thus, I end-up writing the procedure to lock the table so that other user should not get the dirty read of MAX value.

```
Create table D(Id int , Name varchar(100))

Begin Tran 
    DECLARE @i int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM D with (tablockx, holdlock))
    Print @i ;

    Insert into D values ((@i + 1), 'ANAS')

    SELECT * FROM D 

    --COMMIT 
Rollback
```

This code lock the table until query commits or rollback. I have two question from this 1) Is this code guarantee to have exclusive lock on table? 2) In my quick read **tablockx** can help perform lock for read also whereas **holdlock** help to prevent the changes in row I am working in locked session, but is this rightly used because I think *holdlock* may actually not required

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It may make more sense to use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows being manipulated by the _other_ statement, e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. (`OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.) Then reuse that data for the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are asking the right question.  You need the current value not to be changed and no insert. With SERIALIZABLE you may not need (updlock).

I am not positive about this answer.  You should do your own testing.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
Begin Tran 
    DECLARE @i int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM D with (updlock))
    Print @i ;

    Insert into D values ((@i + 1), 'ANAS')

    SELECT * FROM D 

    --COMMIT 
Rollback
```

identity or sequence number are better approaches

Comment: @paparazo since identity and sequence will increment by interval (let say +1) this is not solving the problem because all the rows will have their own unique value. As mention in post I want values in two rows of a single column to be identical and this will increment let say +1 every time next two rows are added then newly added rows will have similar identical value in those two.

Comment: @Anas Sure smells like a questionable data design to